# jQuery Deferred / Promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I am trying to understand how Promises works using jQuery.
this is my sandbox:

```
    function test1() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred()
        setTimeout(function() {
             deferred.resolve(1);
             //deferred.reject(2);
        }, 2000);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    function test2() { 
        var deferred = $.Deferred()
        setTimeout(function() {
             deferred.resolve(2);
            // deferred.reject(2);
        }, 1000); 
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    function doTest(){
        $.when(test1()).then(
            function (a) {
                console.log('test1 finished', a)
                return test2();
            },
            function (a) {
                console.log('something failed in test1', a)
            }
        ).then(
            function (b) {
                console.log("test2 finished", b);
            },
            function (b) {
                console.log("something failed in test1", b);
            }
        );
    }
```

It works as I expected - writting:

> test1 finished 1
>
> test2 finished 2

But when I change it like below:

```
        function test1() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred()
        setTimeout(function() {
            // deferred.resolve(1);
             deferred.reject(2);
        }, 2000);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    function test2() { 
        var deferred = $.Deferred()
        setTimeout(function() {
             deferred.resolve(2);
            // deferred.reject(2);
        }, 1000); 
        return deferred.promise();
    }
```

it write to console:

> something failed in test1 2
>
> test2 finished undefined

what is not true, because test2 haven't been even executed.

I expect, that "test2 finished undefined" shouldn't be displayed.

I guess something is wrong in second then, but what?

Comment: You either will need to call `test2` in the error handler as well, or you will need install the "test 2 finished"-logging result handler only on the `test2()`  promise, or you will need to not catch the error before it.

Comment: Sounds like you learned about Deferreds/Promises in jQuery 1.x/2.x and you are now using 3.x, which behaves differently (aka properly). In 3.x, a catch handler (2nd arg of `.then()`) catches by default - the promise chain continues down its success path unless an error is thrown/rethrown, or a promise is returned that is (eventually) rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually in the onRejected function of the first `then`. Specifically, because you're "returning a value" (undefined), then the next `then` handler in the chain treats this as a *fulfilled* promise.

```
    $.when(test1()).then(
        function (a) {
            console.log('test1 finished', a)
            return test2();
        },
        function (a) {
            console.log('something failed in test1', a)
            // Your problem is here.
        }
    ).then(
        function (b) {
            console.log("test2 finished", b);
        },
        function (b) {
            console.log("something failed in test1", b);
        }
    );
```

This can be useful in some cases:

```
$.when(riskyFunction()).then(
  function (value) {
    return processValue(value);
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return defaultValue;          // This lets you recover...
  }).then(function (value2) {
    return processValue2(value2); // so this handler runs regardless of
                                  // riskyFunction's return value.
  });
```

By comparison to synchronous code, this matches a narrow `try` block:

```
try {
  a = test1();
  b = test2();
} catch (e) {
  console.log('something failed in test1', a)
}
console.log("test2 finished", b);  // this runs even if test1 or test2 fails,
                                   // but in those cases b is undefined!
```

Instead, you should remove your error handler and catch errors at the very end, or at least `return $.reject(a)` or `throw a` to keep following the error chain in your `then` handlers.